# cannot install jdbc module in RHEL 6 for my nodejs app

Tags: node.js, npm, node-java

I have been trying to install jdbc in RHEL6 but keeps on getting

```
error Linux 4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64
9680 error argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.3.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "install"
9681 error node v4.3.0
9682 error npm  v2.14.12
9683 error code ELIFECYCLE
9684 error java@0.4.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
9684 error Exit status 1
9685 error Failed at the java@0.4.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
9685 error This is most likely a problem with the java package,
9685 error not with npm itself.
9685 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
9685 error     node-gyp rebuild
```

I am attaching the npm-debug
http://pasted.co/c60c05d2

The install worked prefectly when i tried it on windows 7 .

I am stuck on this for days. Please help

Edit: please find the full logs here npm-debug http://pasted.co/70275c54

nodejs log http://pasted.co/fc4729ea

Comment: Can you post the rest of the console output that comes before what you're currently posted?

Comment: @mscdex i have update the log @ http://pasted.co/70275c54

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean `npm-debug.log`, I meant the actual console output. The latter actually provides the real cause of the error.

Comment: @mscdex I am trying to deploy the app in aws eb. I am attaching th log downloaded. Please consider only the last builds error http://pasted.co/fc4729ea

Comment: I'm not seeing the same error in your other linked logs, so I'm not sure about that particular error. The errors in your other linked logs have to do with the execution of a start script but the `package.json` file can't be found, which is where you'd have such scripts defined.